# Need to install compendium to install EventAdmin?

Tags: osgi, osgi-bundle

I have an application which receives high volume events (some metrics data) from web applications. I have a non-osgi application that receives these events and is responsible for forwarding these events to osgi bundle. I am trying to use EventAdmin for this communication. I looked at [EventAdmin is null in maven-osgi project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21100900/eventadmin-is-null-in-maven-osgi-project) but does not clearly answer a few questions.

I want to install the EventAdmin service (at non-osgi application level). I am using "org.osgi.service.event.EventAdmin". However, there is no separate jar for this. It is part of compendium jar. Do I need to install compendium jar?

If I don't do above, the reference I get back from this call is always null:
        ServiceReference ref = context.getServiceReference(EventAdmin.class.getName());

Any pointers are highly appreciated

Thanks
Masti

Answer (score 1):

Event admin is for communication inside one OSGi framework. You can not use it outside of OSGi or for communication between OSGi containers. For your case I recommend to use jms for communication or if this is too slow then RabbitMQ or HornetQ may work. There is also work in progress to define remote events for OSGi but it is not yet available. One possible combination of event admin and jms might be to receive jms in one bundle and forward the event over event admin. So your business code bundle can abstract from jms.

Comment: Thanks Christian. I was using this to communicate between my application and an osgi bundle: bundleContext.registerService(DATA_TYPE, dataHolderMap, null); This works fine for low volume of calls. I thought in a similar way you could use EventAdmin on single JVM

Comment: If you are in the same vm then you at least have a chance to use OSGi services. From outside the OSGi framework you can only access classes and interfaces that are not in bundles. So you could try to add the enterprise spec jar to your normal classpath and export the package of the event admin service using the org.osgi.framework.system.packages.extra option of the framework. Then you should be able to retrieve the service from outside the framework.